# How to show values on pie or bar graph chart in php using chart.js

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I want to show values on graphs. i search alot but could not find my solution. 
Here is the code below:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
ctx.height = 100;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {        
      labels: <?php echo json_encode($Division); ?>,        
      datasets: [{
         label:    'Target',
         data: <?php echo json_encode($TARGET_QTY); ?>,
        //backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", 
        backgroundColor: "rgb(231, 123, 126)", 
        borderColor: "rgb(219, 219, 219)",
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    {                     
        label: 'Actual',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($DISPATCH_QTY); ?>,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 191, 255)",
        borderColor: "rgb(252, 252, 252)",
        borderWidth: 1
    }
]
},
options: {
responsive: true,
  tooltips: {
        "enabled": false
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display:false,
        },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        // position:"bottom",
        text: 'Target vs Actual Dispatch'
    },
    hover: {
        // Overrides the global setting
        mode: 'label'
    },
    animation: {
    duration: 1,
    onComplete: function () {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
            ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i)
        {
            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                var data = dataset.data[index];
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
            });
        });
    }
  },
    /*legend: {
        display: true,
        // position : "bottom",
        labels: {
            fontColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        }
    }*/
}
});
</script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="chart">
                <canvas id="barChart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></canvas>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I search alot but could not show values in the bar graph. In this code value will be shown on the top of the graph but could not show on the bar. i want to show value on the bars of graph. either its a bar chart or pie chart. i use chart.js library. Please help me to get rid of this  situation. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I tried your code, working perfectly here. you need to check your `json_encode` data, it must be surrounded by square brackets.

Comment: i don't think so `json_encode`  is an issue. @bha